# fail to delete data from TDengine

Tags: sql, tdengine

I want to delete some data from a table.

First, I executed the following sql:

```
select count(1) from dclm_device.device_int where identifier = "water_level";
```

I can see "Query OK, 1 rows in database"

However, when I tried to delete the data from this table, it failed.

The delete statement is :

```
from dclm_device.device_int where identifier = "water_level";
```

The output is:

> DB error: invalid input

I think the statement is correct, so what may be the problem?

Comment: Isn't the "delete" clause missing? "delete from dclm_device.device_int where identifier = "water_level";"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to its development document.

https://docs.tdengine.com/taos-sql/delete-data/#

```
DELETE FROM [ db_name. ] tb_name [WHERE condition];
```

condition: Optional parameter, specifies the data filter condition. If no condition is specified all data will be deleted, so please be cautions to delete data without any condition. **The condition used here is only applicable to the first column, i.e. the timestamp column.**

So, the `where` condition you used should be a timestamp.